# My code is returning a blank value when it needs to prompt for input and provide correct or incorrect percentage

Tags: python-3.x

The code I have written is given below. Out of 20 elements already present, the code needs to prompt me to enter 5 values which it does if I use half the code but then when I want it to also provide me percentage of correct and incorrect answers, it is giving me a blank line. What is wrong?

---

```
list1=!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftLearning/intropython/master/elements1_20.txt -o elements1_20.txt
    elem_unique = list1.readines()
    correct_guess = []
    incorrect_guess = []
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0
    guess_counter = 0

print("List any 5 of the first 20 elements in the Periodic table\n")
elem_input = []
counter = 0
while counter < 5:
    Input_name = input("Enter the name of an element: ")
    if Input_name in elem_input:
        print(Input_name, "was already entered, no duplicates allowed")
        pass
    elif Input_name == "":
        Print("Nothing was entered! Please enter a name")
        pass
    else:
        elem_input.append(Input_name)
        counter += 1
        print ("you entered: ", elem_input)
        while guess_counter < 5:
            for Input_name in elem_input:
                if Input_name in elem_unique:
                    correct_guess.append(Input_name)
                    guess_counter += 1
                    correct += 1
                    else:
                        incorrect_guess.append(Input_name)
                        guess_counter += 1
                        incorrect += 1
                        percentage_correct = correct * 20
                        print(percentage_correct, "% correct!")
                        print("Found: ", correct_guess)
                        print("Not Found: ", incorrect_guess)
```

---

I expect the output to be
Enter the name of an element:
Enter the name of an element:
Enter the name of an element:
Enter the name of an element:
Enter the name of an element:
80% correct
20% incorrect

Comment: This code does not run. Please post the actual code you are using. For instance, you have a print statement where `Print` is spelled with a capital P. You also have a variable `guess_counter` in your while statement that is not initialized before you use it. It can't be the actual code. Also when you replace it, please put 3 backticks ` at the beginning of the code section and 3 at the end so the indentation is correct.

Comment: Hi Deepstop, That is the problem, this code does not run. It runs if I use only half of it till "print ("you entered: ", elem_input)". Guess_counter is initialized in the beginning to 0.